# 'int' object is not iterable in arrays with use height

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, conditional-statements

I'm having a problem with this code, I need to calculate the height of a certain number of people and after that:

- show the smallest and largest height of the group
- the average height of the women
- the percentage difference between the amount of men and women

When running the code, an error appears:

```py
print('A menor e maior altura do grupo são: {} e {}'. format({min(altura_grupo)}, {max(altura_grupo)}))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

```py
sizegroup = int(input('Digite o tamanho do grupo:'))
 
 
altura_grupo = []
altura_h = []
altura_m = []
grupo_homens = []
grupo_mulheres = []
 
for num in range(sizegroup):
 sexo = input('Sexo (M | F):')
  altura_grupo = int(input('Digite a sua altura (em cm):'))
  if sexo in 'Mm':
   grupo_homens.append(sexo)
   altura_h.append(altura_grupo)
  else:
   grupo_mulheres.append(sexo)
   altura_m.append(altura_grupo)
 
 
print('A menor e maior altura do grupo são: {} e {}'. format({min(altura_grupo)}, {max(altura_grupo)}))
print('A média das alturas femininas é:', {sum(altura_m)/lens(grupo_mulheres)})
print('A quantidade de homens é {} e a diferença percentual com a quantidade de mulheres é de:{}'. format(lens(grupo_homens), (lens(grupo_homens)-lens(grupo_mulheres))*100))
```

When running, the code must:

1. Receive the number of people in a group
2. Enter gender and height and with this, present the smallest and largest height of people
3. The average height among women
4. The percentage difference between men and women

Comment: Please repost your code with proper formatting. It should not have `>` before each line, and the indentation needs to be correct.

Comment: `min(altura_grupo)` doesn't make sense. `altura_grupo` is a single integer, not a list of integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
altura_grupo = int(input('Digite a sua altura (em cm):'))
```

is replacing the list with the input, not adding to the list. Use `append()` to add to a list.

```
altura_grupo.append(int(input('Digite a sua altura (em cm):')))
```

Then you will be able to get the minimum and maximum of the list.